# How to remove gnome-sound-recorder?

Tags: uninstall

Does anyone know how to uninstall gnome-sound-recorder?

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 1):

Type in Terminal (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-media
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: @AndyKos please mark as answer ([click tick mark next to the answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer))